# how to remove quotations for ObjectId imported from csv

Tags: mongodb

I have imported a csv file into a collection,

My document saved like

```
"_id" : "ObjectID(53874d952f92e2af1a5f0afb)"
```

I was unable to query this

Can anyone help me to remove quotations for `ObjectId`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your collection name is myCollection.
Do this :

```
db.myCollection.forEach(function(doc) { 
   var oldId = doc._id;
   var newIdStr =  doc._id.replace(/ObjectID\((\w+)\)/g,"\$1");
   var newObjId = ObjectId(newIdStr);
   doc._id = newObjId;
   db.myCollection.save(doc);
   db.myCollection.remove({_id:oldId});
});
```

Comment: Here,it is not updating, it is adding a new record with a new id, but yes, we need to delete the old record. Have corrected that.

Answer (score -1):

CSV does not fully preserve the types of your fields and can present strings and integers (not Object_ids). If I were you, I would write an a parser in the most suitable language and convert your _id in objectIds there.

Another approach (if your _ids are not important) you can change _id in csv header to any other name and during the import mongo will create new ids, then you will go and remove your created field.

Next time you can use [mongodump and mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/) to preserve the types.

Comment: again, I am facing same problem. I think we can't import a csv file. Need to export .json file, No alternate solution for me